# How to build an inventory or list of selected objects that the hands have picked up and placed

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion

there are cube objects in my game each assigned a letter from the alphabet 26 cubes - A-Z
The hand controller can pick up a cube and place it but how and where do I find out what has been picked up and placed. 
Would this be a script that needs to be added or is there something in unity that already supports this.

I have watched youtube videos where this works but it doesn't seem to apply to the unity controller as the game object so guidance is needed on where to look/start / how is this done in other VR/3d games because I know it is possible

Comment: Have you tried using collision detection? when the hand leaves the object it should trigger OnCollisionExit for both objects. you can implement the tracking at these points.

Comment: See also trigger colliders.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use collision detection on the object after it has been placed
Once the cube is dropped ontop of the collision detector it is registered

The same collision detector could be applied for each object but I found it easier to use the first way
Thank you for your help